# Passing parameter in snowflake stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I want a suggestion for snowflake scenerio where user updates multple rows on dashboard at a time. The rows will come to snowflake using stored proc call via parameter and entire rows are to be inserted in target table in snowflake.

I have asked developer to send me multiple rows to be stored like below in proc call.

```
[[row1],[row2],[row3],[row4] .....]
```

1. Is variant dataype able to handle above or do I need to use text?
2. If there is alternative to list of lists such as json etc?

If there is better solution to this kindly suggest

Comment: JSON feels like the appropriate format for having an application send in records to a procedure. You can handle it natively in the proc that way instead of rolling your own.